# Cannot find Windows 7 in Grub Customizer

Tags: 12.10, grub2, dual-boot, windows-7, wubi

Once again, I find myself back to the "anywhere, Anything" forum of Ubuntu... Just awesome I say...

Any ways, After I installed the Grub Customizer 3.0.(1)? I ran it and I am not seeing Windows7. 
I installed Ubuntu 12.10, then ran update.
2. I want windows 7 as my primary boot system.
3. What are the exact steps for locating my windows 7, and then how do I place it in the Grub?

I dont wanna messa anything up....after running `fdisk -l`, this is what is listed:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe227662f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     3074047     1536000   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2         3074048   536594431   266760192    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       536594432   599508991    31457280    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda4       599508992   603703295     2097152    6  FAT16
/dev/sda5       536596480   599508991    31456256    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

So now what is the process?  Could you please help... not shutting Ubuntu down till I get it right.. ;)

Comment: I also run the update after adding the "install MBR to /dev/sda2 which from above is where I think my windows7 is located...here is the result of the update after installing MBR...    sudo update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-21-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Skipping Windows 7 (loader) on Wubi system
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
Skipping Windows 7 (loader) on Wubi system
done

Answer (score 2):

Windows is not added for a Wubi install. Wubi boots via the Windows Boot Manager already so trying to get grub to load Windows by default is pointless (it just takes you back to the Windows Boot Manager).

Note if you did get Grub to boot Windows (it's possible), and set Ubuntu as the default in the Windows Boot Manager, they'll just keep going from one boot menu to the other. If you did this and **also** set the `Time to display operating systems` in the Windows Boot Manager to 0, then Windows cannot boot. That's the reason Windows was removed from the Grub menu for all Wubi installs.

One important thing that's not always clear with Wubi: the first time you install Wubi it sets a flag in the Windows boot manager to go straight to Ubuntu without prompting. This makes some people think that Ubuntu has taken over. That's not the case. Simply reboot and you'll be prompted to choose between Windows and Ubuntu. That might be what happened here.

Comment: Mine actually gave me the prompt of which system i want to boot, from the beginning..  so after installing, I dont have to do anything then?  Greatly appreciated... it was such a headache.  im not really a n00b, just n00bed to this process ahaha..   But after I install it, what do I do then, because it will not boot a second time.. I have no trouble with windows at all....  Just the re-boot process for ubuntu

Comment: What happens when you try to boot after the first boot? Maybe you tweaked something with the grub-customizer but it's usually robust. If you just did a fresh install it's probably easy enough to just reinstall.

Comment: My screen just stays black, sometimes i get a single beep.  so when I re-install for instance...Do I change anything at all? because it loads fine the first time.  then on second boot, it will not load. I always have the options for windows or Ubuntu..but second boot in Ubuntu fails... I have a 30 gig partition...what is the correct way to set up a EXT4 partition and how much should I dedicate to this?  I have 4gb total RAM. maybe that is the problem... I am using the Windows Installer, not a boot CD.

Comment: At what time do I set the EXT4? before,during or after install? Then after that... Do I change anything in Ubuntu, or do I leave the grub alone... I just wanna be able to choose which system at boot screen that I can use.  doesnt matter which is primary or what not, if I dont have to change anything, id rather it be that way

Comment: Wubi is a way to try out Ubuntu. It sets up a virtual partition that is `ext3` (if you install from just `wubi.exe`). You don't have to do anything other than select it at boot. If you get a black screen at boot and it doesn't boot (after waiting 2 minutes), you likely have some hardware issue (graphics card like nvidia or radeon) that needs `nomodeset` at boot. If you want to use a partition you have to install from the DVD or a USB.

Comment: I actually have it figured out now... I greatly appreciate the info... I also downloaded BCD, which was a MBR program that allows you to place a grub into a HD. It also allows you to select which is the default operating system.  I am considering losing windows al-together and just use ubuntu alongside BackTrack 5 R3.  Also, I didnt have to really change anything in the GRUB after installation of either above mentioned.  It pretty well handles it by itself.

Comment: So...with that said, I now have Windows 7 on the largest part of the HD, Ubuntu reserved on about 50GB and of course, my baby, BT5... hahah... it's also reserved with about 75GB.  I use it often for multi-purposes.  I advocate NO ILLEGAL ACTIVITES!!!!!!! Thus, as such even simple steps sometimes become clouded and confusing when over-thought and I really want to take out my time to say thanks to all of you who took the your time out to nudge me along too.  So it goes with outsaying, If you need me, or have a question and I can help, I most certainly will.

Comment: Be Safe, Remember to wrap up when Testing and if you don't know, Just ask!